# CasperJS fill form - input name has square bracket

Tags: javascript, css-selectors, casperjs

I'm trying to submit in Drupal 7.

The input name has square bracket as below:

```
<textarea class="text-full form-textarea" id="edit-body-und-0-value" name="body[und][0][value]" cols="60" rows="4"></textarea>
```

I'm trying to use standard way:

```
casper.waitForSelector("form input[name='title']", function() {
    this.fillSelectors('form#post-node-form', {
        'input[name = title ]': 'White title here',
        'input[name = body[und][0][value] ]': 'Write body content here'
    }, true);
});
```

But it return error:

```
FAIL Errors encountered while filling form: no field matching css selector "input[name = body[und][0][value] ]" in form
```

I've tried to escape using `\` but still not works.

Comment: If any of the given answers solved your problem, you may [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/266187) one of them. If it didn't, then please expand on what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `x-path` or `casper.evalute` method if it couldn't work by x-path.

For example:

```
casper.thenEvaluate(function(term) {
    document.querySelector('input[name="q"]').setAttribute('value', term);
    document.querySelector('form[name="f"]').submit();
}, 'CasperJS');
```

Answer (score 0):

You should quote the attribute value you're trying to match with CSS selectors:

```
'input[name = "body[und][0][value]" ]'
```

Comment: which one of the answers that accepted ? @Artjom B.

Comment: @gumuruh None of the answers were accepted. The OP simply vanished after asking the question.